# How to do a "prismatic"/linear/slider constraint in cannon js?

Tags: cannon.js

I'm probably missing something obvious but how do I do a constraint for something like a piston?

FWIW Really enjoying playing with this code.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Looks like cannon.js project is dormant. I've switched to oimo. I also tried ammo.js which I didn't have much luck with. Very little documentation for any of the three.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the included `CANNON.Constraint` classes are just for constraining two objects to move relative to one another. That doesn't seem helpful here, since you want to constrain movement of *one* body to a specific axis.

It's not elegant, but you can just override the body's position on every step. For example:

```
var body;

var axes = [
  {axis: 'x', max: 1, min: 0},
  {axis: 'y', max: 0, min: 0},
  {axis: 'z', max: 0, min: 0},
];

axes.forEach(function (a) { 
  if (body.position[a.axis] > a.max) {
    body.position[a.axis] = a.max;
    body.velocity[a.axis] = 0;
  } else if (body.position[a.axis] < a.min) {
    body.position[a.axis] = a.min;
    body.velocity[a.axis] = 0;
  }
});
```

If your axis isn't one of x/y/z, this same approach should still work, but there will be more math. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cannon.js does not yet implement prismatic constraint. If you want to contribute with an implementation, read more on [Cannon.js' github page](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js).